# How to decide how much memory to allocate to JVM on 8GB RAM?

Tags: java, spring, memory-management

May be I can provide more information, but I'm not sure what would help?

It's a spring/hibernate app with calls going back to the database on another server, or service calls to other server where more java classes reside (another 8gb RAM box like the one I'm configuring right now).

How can I decide what is a good size to allocate for properties such as -xms, -xms, -maxPermSize etc.
App consumes on 40% of real memory and less than 10% swap space when configured to use 
                 -XMs=512m -Mmx=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

How is the performance affected when I allot a lot more minimum heapSize than it runs comfortably on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you keep the app running for some time and then use `jconsole` utility to check the memory usage stats. It will provide you with all the information you need about memory usage so you can modify the settings accordingly. `jconsole` comes bundled with Sun/Oracle JDK.

Comment: As a side note, since Java SE 7 u 40 you can use [Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/index.html).